# How to use formatting in python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a problem with the formatting. So I have a dictionary that is in the string data type (data_fraction_info):

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
    city = str(cities[i])
    pop = str(population[i])
    data_fraction_info = "{'type': 'Feature','properties': {'message': %s %s,'iconSize': [60,60]},'geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': ['76.9000','43.2500']}}," % (city, pop)
print(data_fraction_info)
```

However it only prints:

```
{'type': 'Feature','properties': {'message': Nur-Sultan 1078362,'iconSize': [60,60]},'geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates':['76.9000','43.2500']}}
```

Where **Nur-Sultan 1078362** is not covered by blockquotes but I want this output:

```
{'type': 'Feature','properties': {'message': 'Nur-Sultan 1078362','iconSize': [60,60]},'geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates':['76.9000','43.2500']}}
```

where **"Nur-Sultan 1078362"** is covered by the blockquotes.

Could someone help me, please?
I would be very thankful for your answer.

Comment: You do not have a dictionary. You have a string that looks like a repl() of a dict with data in it might look like. If you want to prepare strings of data, create the dict as usual and use json to stringify it.

Comment: Do you try to add to template string before and after city with data quotes or escaped quotes `\'`: `'%s %s'`

Comment: Thank you, for helping me! You are so kind!

Answer (score 0):

There is one method to format strings in python and it f"{variable_name}"

Answer (score 0):

You can put quotes around the data is to be inserted:

```py
data_fraction_info = "{'type': 'Feature','properties': {'message': '%s %s','iconSize': [60,60]},'geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': ['76.9000','43.2500']}}," % (city, pop)
```

But since Python3, you shouldn't use `%`. You should use `.format` or f-strings.

```py
data_fraction_info = "{'type': 'Feature','properties': {'message': '{0} {1}','iconSize': [60,60]},'geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': ['76.9000','43.2500']}},".format(city, pop)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in the way I wanted to!

Comment: In that case please mark it as the accepted answer.